# Open window from objective-c OSX

Tags: cocoa, nswindowcontroller

so on start I sorry ;-)
I would open Window from my plugin/library
I want to use xib because is simpler than writing code and positioning.

Of course I have MyWindow.xib

`NSWindowController *windowController = [[NSWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"MyWindow"];
[windowController.window contentView];`

window is not open

How to do it ?

Comment: Have you tried `showWindow:`? Or the various `orderX` (`orderFront:` etc.) methods?

Comment: Oh yeah, this works ;-) thanks a lot.